# Windows Logon not working through TeamViewer

Tags: windows, teamviewer

I try to connect to my Administrator account when opening a TeamViewer Session. When the session is locked or no user is logged in I see the normal Windows login. When I put in the password I get a "Username or password is false" error. When I enter the same password through a keyboard that is attached to the server with USB it works.

I allowed Remote Desktop for the user, I allowed Windows logon in the Team Viewer Options --> Security and I have a password that is longer than 6 symbols. What is the problem here?

Server is windows 2008 Enterprise R2

Comment: Maybe you use a different keymap or something? You can test this by "switching" the user account and type something in the account name box

Answer (score 1):

Both team viewer version should match each other. So try to upgrade team viewer. Some times you need to ensure that keyboard is enabled on the client end and remote control is activated. Try to uncheck "send key combinations" from "Action" menu then you can type on remote computer again. Try to disable UDP from Extras-->Options-->Advanced. Hope these solutions will help you.